# Multiples modales, mismo estilo en Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, modal, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web usando `Vue2` y `BootstrapVue`, y tengo una serie de 6 elementos (de los cuales sólo voy a subir 3 aquí, por cuestiones prácticas), todos iguales estéticamente, pero con distinto contenido, rendereados mediante un `v-for`. A ellos les estoy agregando un modal con Bootstrap, el cual podría generarlo de la misma manera, pero el detalle es que no quiero que cargue la página con los 6 modales en segundo plano. Quiero generarlos en el momento del click en el botón "Learn More" y que se muestre la información correspondiente a ese elemento del array en mi archivo `.vue`.
No sé cómo hacer para relacionar mediante un `index` al elemento el cual quiero que se muestre la información.
A continuación adjunto mi código:

**Component.html**

```
<div id="blocks">
    <b-container>
        <div class="cards">
            <div class="card" v-for="card in cards">
                <img :src="card.image" :alt="card.mainTitle">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h5>{{card.mainTitle}}</h5>
                    <p>{{card.text}}</p>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="showModal">Learn More</i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </b-container>
    <b-modal ref="modal" centered hide-footer>
        <div class="d-block text-center">
            <h3>{{cards.mainTitle}}</h3>
            <p>{{modalText}}</p>
        </div>
    </b-modal>
</div>
```

**Component.vue**

```
export default {
  name: 'benefits',
  data () {
    return {
      cards: [
        {
          image: require('../../assets/image1.jpg'),
          mainTitle: 'Title1',
          text: 'Text1',
          modalText: 'Modal text content1'
        },
        {
          image: require('../../assets/image2.jpg'),
          mainTitle: 'Title2',
          text: 'Text2',
          modalText: 'Modal text content2'
        },
        {
          image: require('../../assets/image3.jpg'),
          mainTitle: 'Title3',
          text: 'Text3',
          modalText: 'Modal text content3'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showModal () {
      this.$refs.modal.show()
    },
    hideModal () {
      this.$refs.modal.hide()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: y para evitar usar el index (que tendria que ver como se hace), no usas otra propiedad? que sea una de los items de cards[]? y que el modal este bindeado a esa propiedad? ;)

Comment: Es un buen punto @gbianchi! Ahora voy a pensar un poco cómo podría ser.

Comment: Realmente no lo puedo sacar. Apreciaría una mano! Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer lo que necesitas, vamos a crear una variable mas en el entorno de data, que contenga la card a mostrar:

```
data(): {
    return {
        cards: [
                {
                    image: '../../assets/image1.jpg',
                    mainTitle: 'Title1',
                    text: 'Text1',
                    modalText: 'Modal text content1',
                    index: 0 //ESTA LINEA ES IMPORTANTE
                },...
        ],
        ModalCard: {}
    }
 }
```

La idea detras de esto, es pasarle al modal la card seleccionada.

Ahora lo que sigue se puede hacer de varias formas. Tu modal debe quedar asi:

```
<b-modal ref="modal" centered hide-footer>
    <div class="d-block text-center">
        <h3>{{this.modalShow.mainTitle}}</h3>
        <p>{{this.modalShow.modalText}}</p>
    </div>
</b-modal>
```

Pero la forma de saber la carta seleccionada, puede variar, a buscarla por indice, o pasar directamente la card a buscar. Para eso, en el v-for vamos a hacer lo siguiente dentro del boton mostrar:

```
<div class="card" v-for="card in cards">
    <img :src="card.image" :alt="card.mainTitle">
    <div class="card-content">
        <h5>{{card.mainTitle}}</h5>
        <p>{{card.text}}</p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="showModal(card.index)">Learn More</i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo, le paso a la funcion el indice, que agregue previamente a cada card (a mano). Tambien, se podria hacer algo asi:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="showModal(card)">Learn More</i></a>
```

Y la funcion en este caso va a recibir una card.

La funcion quedara de la siguiente forma:

```
showModal(index) {
    console.debug(index);
    this.modalShow = this.cards[index];
    this.$refs.modal.show()
}
```

Deje el debug, para que se vea que esta recibiendo. Si pasamos la card directamente, la funcion seria algo asi:

```
showModal(theCard) {
    console.debug(theCard);
    this.modalShow = theCard;
    this.$refs.modal.show()
}
```

Extra:

El modal se puede mostrar linkeado a un v-model como:

```
<b-modal v-model="modalShow">
```

agregando en data:

```
modalShow: false
```

Y en la funcion, haciendo algo asi como

```
modalShow = true //false, para cerrarlo
```

Comment: Excelente! Logré hacerlo funcionar gracias a tu esmerada explicación. Muchas gracias!